# Keras/Tensorflow-gpu obscure errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, pycharm

I'm trying to get a DCGAN I wrote to train on the GPU however I'm getting some obscure errors that I dont have normally.

I have python 3.6, using pycharm I created a new venv and installed first tensorflow-gpu, then keras and now I get the below. The code is far too large to host here but it works properly and runs just fine if the regular tensorflow package is installed.

I have Cuda 10.1, up to date nvidia drivers.

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

The above is my code

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\PycharmProjects\low\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\PycharmProjects\low\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\PycharmProjects\low\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```